# remove string in csv

Tags: csv, powershell, replace, trim

i trying write script in powershell, for processing csv.

nagexport.csv

```
server1;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive D: Disk Usage
server13.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com;Drive C: Disk Usage
server14.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com;Drive C: Disk Usage
server21.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com;Drive C: Disk Usage
server5;Drive D: Disk Usage
server5;Drive C: Disk Usage
server6;Drive C: Disk Usage
server6;Drive D: Disk Usage
server6;Drive E: Disk Usage
server61.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com;Drive C: Disk Usage
server61.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com;Drive D: Disk Usage
server18;Drive C: Disk Usage
server18;Drive D: Disk Usage
```

i need proccess/trim this file, for output without domain "xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com".

Requested output is:

```
server1;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive C: Disk Usage
server2;Drive D: Disk Usage
server13;Drive C: Disk Usage
server14;Drive C: Disk Usage
server21;Drive C: Disk Usage
server5;Drive D: Disk Usage
server5;Drive C: Disk Usage
server6;Drive C: Disk Usage
server6;Drive D: Disk Usage
server6;Drive E: Disk Usage
server61;Drive C: Disk Usage
server61;Drive D: Disk Usage
server18;Drive C: Disk Usage
server18;Drive D: Disk Usage
```

thanks for help

...one cofee and cigarettes...
what about?

```
$file = "c:\workspace\NagiosExport.csv"
$newfile = "c:\workspace\nagexportnew.csv"

Get-Content $File | ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match "xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com"){
        $_.hostname.Split('.')[0]
    } Else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $newfile
```

Comment: This is a feasible request however it does seem trivial. Have you tried to fix this on your own?

Answer (score 1):

```
gc C:\temp\NagiosExport.csv | % {$_.replace('.xyz.xxx.asd.qwerty.com','')} | Out-File C:\temp\nagexportnew.csv
```